# Run job locally like gitlab does it with runner images

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a node frontend and in gitlab, the frontend is built using a node slim image and these build commands.

```
  stage: build
  image: node:12.22.12-slim
  when: always
  before_script:
    - echo "Build Frontend Files"
  script:
    - cd frontend
    - npm install
    - npm run buildmycode
```

Is there a way of running the build using the same docker image on my local machine, by passing it the "script" steps like gitlab? How would this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Start the container listed behind `image` and run the commands within that container - did you try that?

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that Node 12 is EOL since more than a year

Comment: @NicoHaase I cannot run that image, mount a volume and exec into that image so I guess that does not work

Comment: Why can't you run that image? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it